# Wpf open all windows when click any of window in taskbar

Tags: wpf

In my wpf application, when user click on menu, a new window will open, and user click an item in that window, another window will open. And when these all window minimized the user, and click any of the window in taskbar, I need to open these three window.

When user click on any of the window, I want to open the three window.

Comment: Set the window state to Maximized for all the windows when one of them is maximized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WindowState is a property on Window.

Subscribe to StateChanged event on the window.

```
this.StateChanged += MainWindow_StateChanged;
```

When this changes to Maximized for one of the windows, update the state for other windows as well.

```
this.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Maximized;
```

Comment: When user click on any of the window in taskbar, I want to open the three window. WindowState.Maximized means the size of the window set to maximized, my requirement is not this.

Comment: Use windowstate normal.

Comment: Not working, when I click any of the window, only the corresponding window opening, not all windows opening.

Comment: Could you please show us some code that you’ve tried.

Comment: Title="Project"  Background="#2B2B37" WindowState="Normal" Width="1300" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" ResizeMode="NoResize" Height="650"

Comment: where have you subscribed to the StateChanged event? Please read the entire answer, now i have added the code too.

Comment: public Home()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            vm = new HomeViewModel();
            this.DataContext = vm;
            this.StateChanged += new EventHandler(Window1_StateChanged);
        }
        void Window1_StateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var project = new Project();
            project.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
            var savePopUp = new SavePopUp();
            savePopUp.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
        }

Comment: Is this method called?

Comment: yes, I think the issue, when windows not minimized, just hide from screen, then the user click to taskbar icon, only the clicked window will open. That time this method not fired.

Comment: In that case, i think you should try making two windows the children of the first window.

Comment: That's great.. any sample

Comment: It’s simple savePopUp.owner=this;